# How to set Windows 10 and above Lock Screen Wallpaper from WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, lockscreen, wallpaper

I want to set Lock Screen Wallpaper of Windows 10 and above from WPF application. I have searched and found the following links are useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785913/5523095

https://superuser.com/a/1274588

Based on the suggestion from the above answers I am trying to change the lock screen wallpaper using the following code.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP", true);           
key.SetValue(@"LockScreenImagePath", @"C:\Users\kumarm\Desktop\Wall.png");
key.SetValue(@"LockScreenImageUrl", @"C:\Users\kumarm\Desktop\Wall.png");
key.SetValue("LockScreenImageStatus", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Flush();
```

But the lock screen wallpaper is not changing. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried creating/editing this key with regedit? does the key get set at all? Also is your application 64bit?

Comment: I was running that code programmatically and trying. Now I tried to create the key in regedit after seeing your comment(I am new to WPF) but I don't see  PersonalizationCSP under CurrentVersion in my system, only Personalization is there.

Comment: @TheGeneral Will this Registry solution support in all Windows 10 OS?

Comment: You should read the docs about Registry and RegistryKey

Comment: I think I would approach this by using windows to manually set a picture as lock screen. Then search my registry using regedit for that file name ( make sure it will be unique ) and see what is set. It's much more likely to be a user setting than machine. I think an app would need to run as admin to change the machine branch.

Comment: Checkout this PowerShell script. It could help you to write the same in C#. https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.PSSetLockScreen/blob/master/ProductivityTools.PSSetLockScreen/ProductivityTools.PSSetLockScreen.psm1

Answer (score 2):

Your code creates the wrong key in the registry. Also, instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` you have used `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

It should be like this:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP", true);
key.SetValue(@"LockScreenImagePath", @"C:\Images\image.jpg");
key.SetValue(@"LockScreenImageUrl", @"C:\Images\image.jpg");
key.SetValue(@"LockScreenImageStatus", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Flush();
```

This code does work, but after that you cannot change the lock screen image in Windows settings - the possibility is blocked with the reference **"Some of these settings are managed by your organization"**, which can be fixed by deleting registry keys, or by setting empty `"LockScreenImagePath"` and `"LockScreenImageUrl"` values in the registry.